# How to find exact cause that makes System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile fail?

Tags: c#, powershell, fusion-log-viewer

The `LoadFile()` function is really giving me a tough time.
I have two assemblies, `Asm1.dll`, and `Asm2.dll` that are being installed in the GAC.
Later, these assemblies are loaded using `LoadFile()` to create a matching type library.

This all works well for `Asm1.dll` (tested in PowerShell):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\MyTools\Asm1.dll")

GAC    Version        Location
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Asm1\v4.0_4.0.30000.0__abcdef123456\Asm1.dll
```

but it does not for `Asm2.dll`

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\MyTools\Asm2.dll")

Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Asm2.dll'
or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."
```

However, both assemblies do exist in my work folder as well as in the GAC:

```
gci C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Asm2\v4.0_2.3.30000.0__abcdef123456\Asm2.dll
gci C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Asm1\v4.0_4.0.30000.0__abcdef123456\Asm1.dll

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
-a----      10 Mar 2021     15:37        1494528 Asm2.dll
-a----      10 Mar 2021     12:47        6749184 Asm1.dll

gci D:\MyTools\Asm1.dll
gci D:\MyTools\Asm2.dll

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
-a----      10 Mar 2021     12:47        6749184 Asm1.dll
-a----      10 Mar 2021     14:00        1494528 Asm2.dll
```

I also tried `LoadFile()` with the full GAC path - with the same results for both assemblies.

From the past I know that after scrubbing the HKCU registry and GAC from ***all*** traces of my components before rebuilding my tools, the problem disappears. But it did resurface this morning after I had updated Visual Studio and rebuilt my tools without first scrubbing everything clean.

The `LoadFile()` function acts like a black box, giving me exactly ***zero*** information about what went wrong. I don't want to work around the problem anymore by "demolishing my entire building when I'm only looking for a blown fuse", figuratively speaking.

So how can I track the root cause of this failure?

**Edit**

@Efie Thank you. The `$error[0]` only points to the `LoadFile()` function as the error source. No additional insights there.

@Ian Kemp, @Jeroen Mostert Thank you for recommending the fusion log viewer.

It does provide some information but still does not indicate the actual cause. On the contrary - the log indicates that assembly binding succeeded while the error message still appears in the PowerShell console.

```
The operation was successful.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Asm2, Version=2.3.30000.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=abcdef123456
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = PowerShell_ISE.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: 
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Asm2\v4.0_2.3.30000.0__abcdef123456\Asm2.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

The log files for both assemblies `Asm1` and `Asm2` are identical apart from the names, versions and the fact that fusion log *explicitly* reported it found `Asm1` in the GAC whereas it didn't do so for `Asm2`:

```
LOG: Post-policy reference: Asm1, Version=4.0.30000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdef123456
LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
```

The log files for both assemblies `Asm1` and `Asm2` are identical apart from the names and versions if I specify the complete GAC path in both calls to `LoadFile()`; including the `Post-policy`-line.

Comment: There *may* be additional information inside the error object. Only the message gets printed to the screen. You can inspect recent errors by inspecting the  ```$error``` variable, like ```$error[0]``` for example. Sometimes there is additional info hidden in there. ```$error[0] | Get-Member``` will get you a list of properties which you can dig into further.

Comment: That black box does have a logging facility. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255669/4137916).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Comment: I'm calling out those who downvoted this question to present a solution!

In the mean time I ran dependency walker. It detected a dependency of Asm1.dll to `OLE32.DLL` (unsurprisingly). But it also detected a circular dependency between `c:\windows\system32\OLE32.DLL` and `c:\program files\powershell\7\API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL` which I consider a bug in PowerShell.
However, temporarily renaming the PowerShell folder removed the circular dependency but did not fix the original problem.

Any more ideas?

Comment: Any solution, I have similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

A pattern I've used in the past is something like this (I'm doing it from memory so might need a tweak to actually work!):

```
try
{
    Add-Type -LiteralPath "c:\temp\myassembly.dll";
}
catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException]
{
    $ex = $_.psbase.Exception;
    foreach( $item in $ex.LoaderExceptions )
    {
        write-host $ex.ToString();
    }
    throw;
}
```

Comment: That returns the exact same information as the exception printed by PowerShell when calling `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\temp\myassembly.dll")`.